# How to create dark box with gray grid on Matlab 3D plot

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

Is there a solution to create this effect on Matlab 3D plots?

[image: plot]

I found this image [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/49542/versions/6/screenshot.jpg), on a script to create cool aligned labels for 3D plots, but actually I was more interested in obtaining that nice gray grid with solid lines, combined with the dark solid box for the 3D axes.

Any idea?

**EDIT:** not on the most recent Matlab (I have R2012b)!

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/grid.html

Comment: `grid` was introduced in R2006, in case your edit is a response of my comment.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid the behaviour I'm looking for is the standard for `grid` from R2015a, but it is definitely not the one for older version.

Comment: If you set `grid on` in R2012b, you got black dashed grid and no boxes around 3D plots. I know I could use a `get(gca)` - `set()` combination, but I don't know exactly which one...

Comment: I tried with `set(gca,'GridLineStyle','-'); set(gca,'GridColor',[208/255 208/255 208/255]);` but I got `The name 'GridColor' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'axes'.` error.

Comment: I cant look at the doc archives to see old axes properties, try yourself, if you can: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/09/03/documentation-for-previous-releases-now-available-online/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution with [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9815-gridcolor) script on file exchange!